# Visual Basic - Getting value from an array with an integer

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I currently Have an array ...

Dim mTeam(10) As String

In the Form load For visual basic i have

```
   'Load Teams
    mTeam(1) = "Oklahoma"
    mTeam(2) = "USC"
    mTeam(3) = "LSU"
    mTeam(4) = "Michigan"
    mTeam(5) = "Georgia"
    mTeam(6) = "Texas"
    mTeam(7) = "Tennessee"
    mTeam(8) = "Ohio State"
    mTeam(9) = "Florida State"
    mTeam(10) = "Miami(FL)"
```

Now what im trying to do, is have the user enter a value between 1-10 in a textbox, and in return. A messagebox will appear with the team name.

Example:

User enters 5 into TextBoxNumber, a message box will apear when i hit button ButtonName, and in that message box it will have the word "Georgia".

---

TextBoxNumber (Name of input value)
ButtonName (button to do all the work and show messagebox)

Any help would be nice, i already have a try catch to have it only take integer values between 1 and 10.

PLEASE NOTE THIS IS FOR VISUAL BASIC , AND IM USING MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 2010

Comment: textbox1.text = mTeam(textbox1.text)

Comment: @Satya The index for an array should be an integer, not a string.  That code will not work if Option Strict is On

Comment: will keep this is mind for future Chris! Thanks

Comment: @UniversityStudent: Be aware that you are creating an array with 11 entries like this, the first (index 0) being ```Nothing```.

Answer (score 3):

You can attempt to convert the user's value to an integer, and if successful return the array value at that index:

```
Dim ind As Integer = -1
If Integer.TryParse(TextBoxNumber.Text, ind) Then
    If ind >= 0 AndAlso ind < mTeam.Length
        MessageBox.Show(mTeam(ind).ToString())
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Holy crap, i cant believe it was that "simple". thanks for the help, was stuck on this part for a few hours!